# Bluetooth file transfer disabled by policy on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I am trying to send a file from my phone Android to a PC running Windows 10,
but it fails. The PC and mobile phone are already paired.

I went into the "Send or receive files via Bluetooth" menu
and selected "Receive Files", but the system returned the message
"...  File transfer is disabled by policy.
Please check with your system administrator.  ..."

[image: image of the error message]

Where can I disable this policy? 
I am logged in with an administrator account.

Comment: This a local machine or is the machine connected to a domain?

Comment: @Ramhound It is a local machine, no domain connection.

Comment: @Drake Is your computer managed by anyone else, despite not being on a domain? It might be worth scanning through `gpedit.msc` if you're running Windows 10 Pro, and if not, if you're familiar with `regedit`, look for any stray DWORDs (which would likely be under Policies keys).

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I fixed the Bluetooth file transfer error message:

1. Open Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Advanced Sharing Settings
2. Scroll down and click the down arrow to open All Networks
3. Click **Enable file sharing for devices that use 40 or 56 bit encryption**
4. Restart your computer

Now you should be able to send files from your PC via Bluetooth to your android phoneImage.

Comment: This worked for me without a reboot. The first attempt actually failed, but that may have been incidental. After that I was able to transfer several files without issue.

Comment: Same here. 1st attempt failed, but next one worked fine.

Comment: Not working for me, after reboot I'm still getting the error message. This happens only when receiving files, while I have no problems sending files from windows to another device...

Answer (score 3):

1. go to services
2. Bluetooth support service
3. click log on tab
4. select "this account"
5. then click browse button and from the dialog box click advanced
6. then click find now
7. select "LOCAL SERVICE"
8. ok
9. remove password and confirm password from the log on screen mentioned in step    (3)
10. start Bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

Check whether **Bluetooth Support Service** is not disabled (`services.msc`), as it was in my case (startup type should be `Manual (Trigger Start)`).

Getting the same error message as the reporter when trying to receive files.

Also when the service was not running, clicking on **Settings > Devices > Bluetooth > More Bluetooth Options** would not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Windows 10 and ASUS_ZOOXS (android 5.0) the process is this.

1. Enter services.msc in search window
2. Click services.msc
3. Right click on Bluetooth Support Service  then choose "stop"
   then do as in the [answer from "Dan Dar3"](https://superuser.com/questions/1054391/bluetooth-file-transfer-disabled-by-policy-on-windows-10/1125356#1125356)
4. Right click on Bluetooth Support Service  then choose "property"
5. Choose log on tab. Then do as in the [answer from "SANDEEP"](https://superuser.com/questions/1054391/bluetooth-file-transfer-disabled-by-policy-on-windows-10/1174943#1174943)
6. Right click on Bluetooth Support Service  then choose "start"
7. If you want to send a file from PC to Android, you should right click bluetooth icon then choose "send a file " ->  double click at android device icon  -> choose file in PC -> then choose "open" -> it will show message in android -> in android  choose "accept file"  -> finish
8. If you want to send a file from Android to PC, you should start on PC side first by right clicking bluetooth icon, ->  choose "receive a file" to wait for a file from Android -> then you work on Android side by  selecting a file from Android to PC -> share -> bluetooth and select PC. Then it will appear in PC to receive file in PC -> finish.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had disabled the service, even though the message said it was a group policy.

Services.msc
Bluetooth Support Service  <--- was disabled, changed to manual (automatic is probably better), started it, and files transferred fine.

I use a Workgroup, not a Domain, so you may experience this differently if you are on a Domain.