# How to share files from an Android phone with Windows 10 via Bluetooth?

Tags: windows-10, android, bluetooth

Using an android device (Android 13) I have paired with a Windows 10 computer in order to transfer files from the Android phone to the Windows computer. However when I try to share a photo from the Android device I see a short popup

```
Bluetooth share: Sent files: 0 successful, 24 unsuccessful
```

No other error message shown, no indication on windows. Restarted both devices, re-established Bluetooth connection. But I does not work. I am unable to send a file from the android device to windows 10.

How can I fix/investigate this annoying problem? Maybe there is an android app which can tell me what is going on and how to fix it? (Yes, sometimes I am dreaming ...)

I did

- run the troubleshooter
- Set **Enable file sharing for devices that use 40 or 56 bit encryption** as suggested [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/1054391/bluetooth-file-transfer-disabled-by-policy-on-windows-10)

Comment: There is no common/default way to share the files between your android device and PC. However you can send and/or receive files by Bluetooth. To receive files by Bluetooth from your Android device simple right click on a Bluetooth icon in your tray and select "Receive files" from the popup menu. Next select files you want to transfer on your phone and select Send by Bluetooth (or something like this).

Comment: Note that Bluetooth sharing seems to be limited regarding the supported file types (at least this is my experience when sending files from PC to Android). Common file types like images are no problem, but other file types can be a problem.

Comment: As others mentioned, I've found Bluetooth file transfer on Windows OS to be problematic. If either is an option, connect by USB, or transfer data directly from µSD card. Also look how to transfer files **for your particular device**.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, you have to start the **Bluetooth File Transfer** tool:

- Settings > Devices > Bluetooth & other devices > Send or receive files via bluetooth (on the right side)
- or launch `fsquirt` from the start menu

Choose **Receive files**, and your PC will wait to receive files shared via Bluetooth. While the window is open, you can share via Bluetooth from your phone.

Once the file transfer has completed, you can choose where to save the file(s).

---

That said, Bluetooth is awfully slow for transferring files. Some other alternatives that are built into windows:

- **Phone Link:** Reliable, can browse and copy photos, but no options for sorting
- **Nearby Share:** Can use wifi or bluetooth, but discovery is pretty unreliable in my experience
- **Shared folder:** more setup involved, but fastest and most reliable. Requires using phone to manage files:

  1. [Sharing a folder in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf)
  2. Use an Android file manager like Cx File Explorer which can access network files
  3. Connect to your PC using hostname or IP, and username/password (depending on settings)
- **USB**: straightforward, but requires a cable